# MS Access repetition of data

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I have a family table and i have a children table. Family table has Family_ID as primary key and Children table has Family_ID as foreign key.

I would like a report where i can list family details and on the bottom i would like to include children details.

Now I inserted a sub report for Children, and I could see both family and children information.

However, there is repetition of family and children info as many times as there are number of children. I would like to show family info only once and show all the children below.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the wizard to insert subreport?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a subreport for that. You can build your report on the 2 tables (join, of course) and use grouping. See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-HA010006894.aspx) for a tutorial.
You will have family data in the Family header, and the children data in the Detail section.

Comment: I think I must disagree with you. I think the idea is that a single family can have multiple children, which is a typical form / subform set-up.

Comment: Prem Shrestha is talking about a report, not a form. You can add group headers and footers in reports and do not need to add subreports for this.

Comment: But I do not believe Prem Shrestha is talking about a small amount of family data, more like a detailed family report, not suited to a group header.